# Response data is not displayed in .jtl file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have modified jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true,jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true properties in Jmeter properties file. Still I am not able to see response data in .jtl file. Help appreciated!

Comment: My response is in json format. Does that have any limitations to store response data?

Comment: Please provide some code samples so that others can more easily help you with your question.

Comment: I can not share the real example. I am testing Restful webservies with Json format. After making above changes, request is getting stored in .jtl file but response data is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using distributed mode to run your tests then it is regular.

If you want the response data you need to set in user.properties:

- mode=Standard

If you're not in this case, then add to Workbench node a Property Display component and see if the properties you have set are taken into account.

If not check if they are not defined in user.properties file

Comment: I am not using distributed mode. I searched for mode in user properties file but could not find the same. When I changed the mode property in jmeter.properties the request data is also not displaying now. Can you please help me to solve this? Is there anything else I have to change?

Comment: I updated my answer, if ok upvote and accept it so that it's helpful to others.

Comment: I checked the properties and they are taken in to account. Please find the properties info:jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results all, jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message true, jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format xml, jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data true, jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error true,jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message true, jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData true.....Please let me know if I am missing any thing